# как правильно прочитать result = {k: v for k, v in sorted(fruits.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

Tags: python, словари, for

есть кусок кода

```
result = {k: v for k, v in sorted(fruits.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

помогите как правильно прочесть (расшифровать)

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: Почитать что делает метод items у словарей. Почитать как работает sorted, и его параметр key. Если нужно — почитать про лябмда-выражения. Почитать как работает dict comprehension (кстати, оно тут излишнее, можно было просто в dict обернуть: `result = dict(sorted(fruits.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))`)

Comment: А вы пробовали эту строку ввести в гугл?
Первая ссылка с подробным объяснением:
https://www.quora.com/What-does-this-Python-code-mean-v-k-for-k-v-in-myArray-items Только у вас словарь отсортирован по значению.

Answer (score 0):

В этом коде в переменную `result` сохраняется словарь `fruits`, отсортированный по ключам.

Например, если словарь `fruits` имеет значение `{'a': 5, 'b': 1, 'c': 8}`, то переменная `result` будет иметь значение `{'b': 1, 'a': 5, 'c': 8}` - как видите, словарь отсортирован по значениям.